# using the maxlength option in cakephp - but it outputs two maxlength values in the html

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm just messing about trying to figure out cakephp which looks like it's going to be a lot of fun.

I have a form input which goes like:

```
echo $form->input('Campaign.title', array('maxLength'=>'76px'));
```

which outputs:

```
<label for="CampaignTitle">Title</label><input name="data[Campaign][title]" type="text" maxLength="76px" maxlength="255" id="CampaignTitle" />
```

notice the two values for the maxlegth. How can I get rid of the second "255" value which seems to be preferred in IE.

Comment: Sorry I'm not a CakePHP expert, but do you really want 'px' in your maxLength?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to pay attention to your capitalization of the html property "maxlength"

Cake will auto determine the max length for certain field types by the length of the database column. In your case you want to override this field's length - a varchar(255) - to be 76 instead of the 255 the field can allow for.

But in your helper call you are setting an attribute "maxLength" - notice the capitalized "L" - which isn't the actual attribute "maxlength".

So - to fix your helper call, remove the "px" and change the key from "maxLength" to "maxlength"

```
<?php echo $form->input('Campaign.title', array('maxlength'=>'76')); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was so sure it was meant to be camel cased I didn't think to check. :)

Answer (score 2):

Why is there a px?

IE doesn't understand the "px" for plain HTML, so it overrides it, and sets it to the default.

Use this

```
echo $form->input('Campaign.title', array('maxLength'=>'76'));
```

Comment: Oh, that worked. Oops, please don't tell anyone ;) that makes it work in IE now. But it still outputs two values. How come? Is there a way to get rid of the 2nd value